# LINQ query Select(...) method not behaving as expected with JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have generated some rather large (hundreds of MB) JSON files that I would like to perform queries on. I am brand new to LINQ, thus my choice of syntax is pretty much copied from tutorials without a full understanding. Here is a simplified version of what my JSON files look like:

```
{
    "Tropes": [{
        "TropeWork": {
            "Name": "Show 1",
            "Description": "....",
            "Tags": ["RebelliousSpirit", "HiddenDepths"],
            "Url": "Series/AlmaPirata",
            "MachineName": "AlmaPirata"
        },
        "Quote": "Quote 1",
    }, {
        "TropeWork": {
            "Name": "Show 2",
            "Description": "....",
            "Tags": ["RebelliousSpirit", "HiddenDepths"],
            "Url": "Series/AlmaPirata",
            "MachineName": "AlmaPirata"
        },
        "Quote": "Quote 2",
    }]
}
```

I would like to extract each instance of "Name" within each TropeWork entry, in this case returning ["Show 1", "Show 2"]. Here is the LINQ query I tried using:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(filename);
JObject db = JObject.Parse(json);

var result = 
    from c in db["Tropes"].SelectMany(i => i["TropeWork"])
                          .Select(i => i["Name"])
                          .Values<string>()
    group c by c
    into g
    orderby g.Key ascending
    select g.Key;
```

It throws this exception once it reaches the `Select(i => i["Name"])` line:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot access child value on
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

When I inspect `i` in the debugger at this point in execution, the JToken is `{"Name": "Show 1"}`. This makes me think that the data *should* be extractable from here, but the `Select(i => i["Name"])` seems wrong (and obviously is). The inspector also shows the properties `i.Name = "Name"` and `i.Value = "Show 1"`, but neither are accessible in my code. This seems like a simple fix, but my severely limited knowledge of LINQ is preventing me from understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you deserialized the json first? You cant really use LINQ like that on a json string.

Comment: I have used [this tutorial](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) as a model, which creates a JObject to perform LINQ queries on with `JObject.Parse(json)`. I could just deserialize to objects but I was hoping this querying system would be better for performance.

Comment: Additionally, if I had attempted the query on just a string, it would have failed at the very beginning rather than making it through the `SelectMany(...)` call.

Comment: The problem is that not every `JProperty` in your source has `["Name"]`. What output do you actually want here?

Comment: For this JSON source example, I want it to return some collection along the lines of `["Show 1", "Show 2"]`.

Comment: You could do something like this: `db.SelectTokens("$.Tropes..TropeWork.Name").Select(t => t.Value<string>())`

Comment: This worked perfectly. If you submit that as an answer, I'll select it. Thank you for bringing this JPath functionality to my attention, it's exactly what I needed yet I had no idea about it.